# How do I add an img tag to a div element on the DOM using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function, dynamic

[index.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7TUf.png)
[index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUrj1.png)

This is the code that I have so far and I keep on getting an error on line 60 which is the last line of the function.

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` returns a node list, not a node.

Comment: Please include all code required in the question itself. Screenshots of code are nearly useless as if we want to replicate the problem we have to retype all your code. Please read about [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in comments by @Daniel, `document.getELementsByClassName("grid")` will return a list of nodes and not a node.

Something like this might work -

```
document.getELementsByClassName("grid")[0].appendChild(xIcon);
```